# Sharing a variable with a closure

Tags: rust

I know, the answers for similar questions already exist... kinda... all that I found were very high level instructions rather than code examples and I couldn't really follow them and I've been stuck in place for days now...

I need to share a variable with a closure. So I have my `MockSlave` struct. I want it to create a vector that can then be shared with the `shell` closure. The current version looks something like this

```rust
impl MockSlave {

    pub async fn new(port: i32) -> Result<Self, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
        let addr = String::from(format!("https://127.0.0.1:{}", port).as_str());
        let endpoint = Endpoint::from_str(addr.as_str())?;

        let commands = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Vec::new()));

        let client = SlaveClient::new(endpoint, CommandProcessors { 
            shell: Some(|command| {
                commands.borrow_mut().push(command);
                Ok(())
            })
        }).await?;

        Ok(MockSlave {
            client,
            commands
        })
    }
```

For clarity, here's `SlaveClient::new`

```rust
pub async fn new(endpoint: Endpoint, processors: CommandProcessors) -> Result<Self, tonic::transport::Error>  {
        let slave = SlaveClient { 
            client: SlaveManagerClient::connect(endpoint).await?,
            processors
        };

        Ok(slave)
    }
```

And here's CommandProcessors:

```rust
pub struct ReadWriteStreamingCommand {
    pub command: Command
}

pub type ReadWriteSteamingCommandprocessor = fn(Box<ReadWriteStreamingCommand>) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>;

pub struct CommandProcessors {
    pub shell: Option<ReadWriteSteamingCommandprocessor>
}
```

Now, the fun part is that VSCode and `cargo build` give me slightly different errors about the same thing.

VSCode says:

```
closures can only be coerced to `fn` types if they do not capture any variables
```

Meanwhile, `cargo build` says

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> tests/api_tests/src/mock_slave.rs:20:25
   |
20 |               shell: Some(|command| {
   |  _________________________^
21 | |                 commands.borrow_mut().push(command);
22 | |                 Ok(())
23 | |             })
   | |_____________^ expected fn pointer, found closure
```

Please help. This is at least my 10th approach to this problem over the course of a week. I am not going to move forward by myself...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fn(Box<ReadWriteStreamingCommand>) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>;
```

This is not the type you think it is. This is the type of pointers to functions that exist statically in your code. That is, functions defined at the top-level or closures which don't actually close over any variables. To accept general Rust callables (including traditional functions *and* closures), you need one of [`Fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html), [`FnMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnMut.html), or [`FnOnce`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnOnce.html).

I can't tell from the small code you've shown which of the three you need, but the basic idea is this.

- Use `FnOnce` if you are only going to call the function at most once. This is useful if you're writing some kind of "control flow" type of construct or mapping on the inside of an `Option` (where at most one value exists).
- Use `FnMut` if you are going to call the function several times but never concurrently. This is what's used by most Rust built-in collection functions like `map` and `filter`, since it's always called in a single thread. This is the one I find myself using the most often for general-purpose things.
- Use `Fn` if you need concurrent access and are planning to share across threads.

Every `Fn` is an `FnMut` (any function that can be called concurrently can be called sequentially), and every `FnMut` is an `FnOnce` (any function that can be called can obviously be called once), so you should choose the highest one on the list above that you can handle.

I'll assume you want `FnMut`. If you decide one of the others is better, the syntax is the same, but you'll just need to change the name. The type you want, then, is

```
dyn FnMut(Box<ReadWriteStreamingCommand>) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>
```

But this is a trait object and hence is not `Sized`, so you can't do much with it. In particular, you definitely can't put it in another `Sized` data structure. Instead, we'll wrap it in a `Box`.

```
pub type ReadWriteSteamingCommandprocessor = 
   Box<dyn FnMut(Box<ReadWriteStreamingCommand>) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>>;
```

And then

```
shell: Some(Box::new(|command| {
            commands.borrow_mut().push(command);
            Ok(())
        }))
```

Comment: i'm a little confused... so should i be using the `FnMut` or the box? So far I added the Box in the `Some` part and in the `ReadWriteSteamingCommandprocessor` type definition, but the error message remains the same

Comment: Both. You need `FnMut` for the closure, but it's an unsized type, so you need the `Box` to be able to contain it.

Comment: sorry. I don't really understand where you want me to use the `FnMut` part :/ the way i see it you want me to modify the same part of the code twice: once with FnMut and once with the Box... I'm confused

Comment: There's a typo in the answer. The last declaration should be `Box<dyn FnMut(Box<ReadWriteStreamingCommand>) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>>` instead of `Box<fn …>`.

Comment: nice catch. as a mostly Java/TS dev I have no idea what I'm looking at and the generic inside of generic inside of generic inside of generic feels like a major code smell :D But I'm not sure if there's any better way to do it in rust... Anyway, i applied the proposed fix, ended up with a new error, added the `move` in `move |command|` and cloned the reference to `commands` and... at this point i don't really know if it works, but it sure compiles! thank you!

Comment: @Jmb Oops! Copy-paste mistake, and I can see how that would make this answer incredibly confusing. `move` is sometimes necessary on closures depending on how you're using them, so that's not unusual. Rust has a much bigger emphasis on type inference than, say, Java, so this kind of type-level manipulation is more normal, since you won't have to actually write out the type nearly as often in Rust.